# What is a fragmented Akka ByteString?

Tags: java, scala, akka

What is a fragmented Akka ByteString and how can I make and use one?
How can one end up with a fragmented ByteString and how to find out that fragmentation has taken place?

Comment: Can you describe a situation where you need to know such information? What did the code tell you?

Comment: For instance in Akka IO you send and receive binary data as ByteString. Nowhere in the docs I found what is presumed. An unfragmented ByteString always or it depends on something?

Comment: Again, why do you need to know? If you are just curious, you are free to read the code as it is open source. `ByteString` takes care of all of the grotty details so that you don't have to. If you have an error that you think relates back to a fragmented `ByteString`, I strongly suggest that you read the code.